# create object with one to one attribute django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create object with set attributes in create function.
This is my profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='profile')
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, 
        related_name='boss')
    FatherName = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='',blank=True)
    NationalCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    birth_date = jmodels.jDateField(null=True, blank=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='',unique=True)
```

and when I create object

```
emp = User.objects.create(first_name=FirstName, last_name=LastName, 
    username=phonenumber,user__PhoneNumber=phonenumber)
```

error is invalid keyword argument for this function.
How can I set PhoneNumber value in Profile model when I try to create User model?

Comment: You can't use `user__PhoneNumber` here. And it makes no sense at all.

Comment: Also you're not following naming conventions and disrespecting the Zen of Python. Using PascalCase for class attributes is a mortal sin. Being incosistent and mixing different cases is a pathway to hell.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to do that in two steps because you are creating two instances. The user instance has to exist before it can be referenced by a ForeignKey. Sth. along these lines will work:

```
user = User.objects.create(first_name=FirstName, last_name=LastName, username=phonenumber)
profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, PhoneNumber=phonenumber)
```

Comment: tanks but because the  PhoneNumber is unique in profile model when i first create user object after that if PhoneNumber is duplicate then user object created and i should delete it in except i want a better solution for handle this bug

Answer (score 2):

You could use Django signals for implicitly handling the `Profile` object creation.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Create profile whenever a user is created.
    """
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```